# Time.timeScale not found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I try to use Time.timeScale I get the following message:

> Time does not contain a definition of timeScale

After googling I realise that I have "another" time in my project, in a class for a REST Api definition, that I guess void the Time:

```
[Serializable]
public class YrData_Class
{
public DateTimeOffset time;
public float air_pressure_at_sea_level;
public float air_temperature;
public float cloud_area_fraction;
public float relative_humidity;
public float ultraviolet_index_clear_sky;
public float wind_from_direction;
public float wind_speed;
public float precipitation_amount;

public string symbol_code12;

public float air_pressure_at_sea_level1;
public float air_temperature1;
public float cloud_area_fraction1;
public float relative_humidity1;
public float wind_from_direction1;
public float wind_speed1;
public float precipitation_amount1;
public string symbol_code1;

public float air_pressure_at_sea_level6;
public float air_temperature6;
public float cloud_area_fraction6;
public float relative_humidity6;
public float wind_from_direction6;
public float wind_speed6;
public float precipitation_amount6;
public string symbol_code6;


public YrData_Class(
    DateTimeOffset time,
    float air_pressure_at_sea_level,
    float air_temperature,
    float cloud_area_fraction,
    float relative_humidity,
    float ultraviolet_index_clear_sky,
    float wind_from_direction,
    float wind_speed,
    float precipitation_amount,

    string symbol_code12,

    float air_pressure_at_sea_level1,
    float air_temperature1,
    float cloud_area_fraction1,
    float relative_humidity1,
    float wind_from_direction1,
    float wind_speed1,
    float precipitation_amount1,
    string symbol_code1,

    float air_pressure_at_sea_level6,
    float air_temperature6,
    float cloud_area_fraction6,
    float relative_humidity6,
    float wind_from_direction6,
    float wind_speed6,
    float precipitation_amount6,
    string symbol_code6
)
{
    this.time = time;
    this.air_pressure_at_sea_level = air_pressure_at_sea_level;
    this.air_temperature = air_temperature;
    this.cloud_area_fraction = cloud_area_fraction;
    this.relative_humidity = relative_humidity;
    this.ultraviolet_index_clear_sky = ultraviolet_index_clear_sky;
    this.wind_from_direction = wind_from_direction;
    this.wind_speed = wind_speed;
    this.precipitation_amount = precipitation_amount;

    this.symbol_code12 = symbol_code12;

    this.air_pressure_at_sea_level1 = air_pressure_at_sea_level1;
    this.air_temperature1 = air_temperature1;
    this.cloud_area_fraction1 = cloud_area_fraction1;
    this.relative_humidity1 = relative_humidity1;
    this.wind_from_direction1 = wind_from_direction1;
    this.wind_speed1 = wind_speed1;
    this.precipitation_amount1 = precipitation_amount1;
    this.symbol_code1 = symbol_code1;

    this.air_pressure_at_sea_level6 = air_pressure_at_sea_level6;
    this.air_temperature6 = air_temperature6;
    this.cloud_area_fraction6 = cloud_area_fraction6;
    this.relative_humidity6 = relative_humidity6;
    this.wind_from_direction6 = wind_from_direction6;
    this.wind_speed6 = wind_speed6;
    this.precipitation_amount6 = precipitation_amount6;
    this.symbol_code6 = symbol_code6;
}
}
```

This is a required class and my understanding is that I cannot change the "time" in YrData_Class, tested that, as it is part of YR API definition.

Is there any good way to solve this problem?

Comment: Directly reference `UnityEngine.Time`? Add `using Time = UnityEngine.Time;' at the top of your file?

Comment: `Time` and `time` are different identifiers.

Comment: @shingo I know that but when testing it voided the Time

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama uhhhh I am so stupid and blind, how could I miss that!!! Tx. Please set that as an answer and I will ok it.

Comment: That's impossible, you must have another class with the name `Time`. If this property causes the problem, the error message should be "DateTimeOffset does not contain..."

Comment: I agree with ProgrammingLlama, but Shingo has a point. The code in the OP doesn’t reference `Time` anywhere…

Answer (score 1):

There's two possible approaches I would suggest.

1. Reference it explicitly: instead of `Time.timeScale`, write `UnityEngine.Time.timeScale` so that it knows it's the `Time` in `UnityEngine` you're referring to.
2. Add `using Time = UnityEngine.Time;` either at the top of your file, or just inside the `namespace` declaration. This will tell the compiler that you mean `UnityEngine.Time` when you write `Time` in that file (or namespace in that file if you have multiple in a single file).